# Programming advice for comparing and swapping multiple values

Tags: c#, database, performance, algorithm, switch-statement

A country is sent to the method and then I want the method to return the continent. The current way I have it set up is a switch statement similar to this. This method can be called several thousand times.

```
 private string changeCountry(string country)
 {   
     switch (country)
     {
        case "Ireland":  return "Europe";
        case "England":  return "Europe";
        case "France":   return "Europe";      
        case "Brazil":   return "America";
        case "Chile":    return "America";
     }
 }
```

The problem is I need to be able to add and remove countries and continents dynamically and this method means that I have to recompile the code when I do add a country or continent.

The solution I was thinking was to have a database table with 2 columns, country and continent which I could add to easily and then have something like this which will be called several thousand times instead.

```
 private string changeCountry(string country)
 {   
     // open db connection
     // Select continent where country = 'country'
     // close db connection
     return continent;
 }
```

Is this a good way or can anyone suggest a better one. I'm not too worries about processing time but I also don't want the process to a huge amount of time. I'm more interested in knowing whether I've overlooked a better solution

Comment: Side notes: I would do 2 tables: continents and countries with one to many relation. And load everything to some kind of collection - just to not call DB several thousand time.

Answer (score 2):

In 3 steps:

1) Have the tables you talked about: Country and Continent, with a foreign key constraint (a Country must be in a Continent).

2) The first time you need that data, load all of it in a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, with the key being the Continent name, and the value being the list of countries associated to it.
Subsequent calls do not load this up again, they reuse that dictionary.

3) When you want the Continent `Con` of a particular Country `Cou` you can do:

```
string Con = myDictOfCountriesToContinent.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Value.Contains(Cou));
```

You can then add any number of countries and continents in DB and your code will benefit from the info.

Please note that if you ask for a country that doesn't exist in DB, the query in 3) will return null. Check accordingly.

Performance-wise, Dictionaries are very good, several thousand times is not an issue. 
What is costy is the round-trip to DB, and you will make 1 at most.

For added speed, you can replace the `List<string>` with a `HashSet<string>`, if the are no duplicate countries for a single Continent.

Answer (score 0):

From maintenance point of view I suggest you create a look up table in database and use this to get the result.

Another solution is that declare keys for each country in config file and create an enum for continents as continents are fixed. Use these data to get the continent for country. If you want to add new country just add it in config and no recompilation is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If content is dynamic, then you cant hard-code the data. I don't think that querying the database several thousand times would effect the performance.

But what is the frequency of those several thousand requests?

Comment: Querying the database several thousand times will most definitely affect performance.

Comment: But not for such a simple query.

Comment: Even if the query is not costy, the round trip is.

Comment: Round-trip depends where the DB is located. I think its in the same machine. In that case, I think it will be all fine because its returning just the continent name.
Also speed depends on the frequency, not the number of request.

Comment: So it's ok to lock him up on one computer for the sake of using bad practice because it's easier? You do not make *several thousand* requests to DB if you don't forcefully need to.

Answer (score 0):

A database will work just fine - unless you want to look around to see if someone provides this as a web service.

If you're worried about slow speeds due to multiple Selects, you could either:

1. Download everything from the database once - put it into memory (as a List, Dictionary or whatever) and update everything once every so often.
2. If you're using mysql - the above but put it into a MEMORY table. This way you can still use the sql code and the performance isn't that much worse.

(Added: To clarify 2 - DON'T put the permanent data in that table. Copy it and use it as a cache. Memory table contents are lost when the database goes down)

Answer (score -1):

Use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary countryContinents = new Dictionary<string,string>();

//add items
countryContinents.Add("Ireland","Europe");

//retrieving
string continent = countryContinents["Ireland"];
//continent equals Europe
```

It could be that the item does not exist and you can check for this:

```
string continent;
if (countryContinents.TryGetValue("Ireland", out continent))
{
    //continent equals Europe
}
```

For the 'no recompile' requirement you can write this dictionary to file and read it in at runtime (when application starts). And write it to file when you have changed the Dictionary or when your application is exited.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam/archive/2010/09/10/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-or-hashtable-in-c.aspx

Comment: This is question about adding data dynamically without recompiling code.

Comment: From where do you think that the data will be loaded in dictionary?

Comment: Whups missed the 'no recompile' requirement. Just serialize the Dictionary to file.